# Google Maps Directions List Jquery Mobile/HTML5

Tags: html, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have the start and end cordinates stored on client device with HTML5 localstorage.To diplay him the route between start and end i have to use google maps driving list(not a map..just the directions in text format) The application is in jquery mobile.

```
<div data-role="content">

    <div data-role="content" id="list"> 
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="myList">
```

can i add that driving list in my listview with id myList?

```
 function gotDirections(geo){
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("myList"));
        var storedlati=localStorage.getItem("text1");
        var storedlongi=localStorage.getItem("text");
        var destilati=localStorage.getItem("text2");
        var destilongi=localStorage.getItem("text3");
        var request = {
            origin:google.maps.LatLng(storedlati,storedlongi),
            destination:google.maps.LatLng(destilati,destilongi),
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What is "google maps driving list"?  Is it just the content of the panel you want (like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-draggableA.html) but without the map)?  Or is there something additional?

Comment: i want the list on the right on the link you gave :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, just set the directions panel on the directionsRenderer, not the map; and don't create the map. Like this [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions_noMap.html)

Comment: As you can see from the code i have given above i have set it to directionsRenderer only var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("myList"));

Comment: Then perhaps a link to a live version of yours would be helpful.  The one I posted works.